# php Cannot redeclare class / Undefined variable Joomla Module

Tags: php, class, oop, joomla, joomla-module

I am experimenting with OOP yet, I am very new to it so,
I have created a module for joomla 2.5.x and inside it's main php file I `require_once` a file with a class like this:

```
require_once(JPATH_SITE.'/modules/'.$module_dir.'/libs/classes.php');
```

classes.php contains this:

```
class experiment
{
    function clean($input)
    {
        return filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
}

$my = new experiment;
```

Then in the module php file I use it like:

```
$name = $my->clean($params->get('name'));
```

Until this point it all behaves normal. But that only when the module appears only once on the same page. If I duplicate the module and use it twice on the same page I get the error `Undefined variable my`. If I change the `require_once` to `require`, I get the error `Cannot redeclare class experiment`. Weird.

I have also tried `if (!class_exists(..` or `if(!isset($my)) { .. }` but I knew it was not going to work.

I will appreciate any kind of help, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include a file, any classes defined in that file are then available globally, but any variables are in the same scope as the include - in this case, just within the function that you originally included the file from.

As a result, when you're using `require_once()`, you're seeing that the second time you try to include it, nothing happens - which is normal, since the file was already included, but the `$my` variable is also not defined - because it went out of scope when the function ended the first time.

When you switch to `require()`, you get a different error, because you're redefining the class.

---

The solution here is to **not** set global variables when you're defining your class. Define the class - and then when you need to use it, create an instance of that class. Don't depend on a *global* variable.

If you're trying to only create one instance of the class (do you really need to do that?), look into using a [singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968154/singleton-pattern-in-php) instead.

Comment: wow ! haha I didn't think of taking the `$my = new experiment;` from inside the classes.php and putting it in the module file. I just did it thanks to your help and it made me laugh that it worked excellent ! thanks man I really appreciate :) it was THAT simple.

Comment: well, I have experimented with this for 2 reasons. 1, so that I am more sure that the function name will not be found again in all Joomla, and 2, of course to learn OOP slowly slowly...

Comment: Thank you man for this, I will try to learn about singleton pattern as well!

Comment: @durduvakis Just don't go too far overboard with singleton. It tends to be heavily overused - and there's often no real reason to restrict a class to just one instance.

Comment: I hope the day that my eyes will open wide with OOP will come soon, cause I am still at a point that I most of the times don't understand what I see and reminds me of when I first saw php code :)